# Implementing asynchronous API endpoints in Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am trying to implement an API that has asynchronous endpoints, for example, create/delete only initiates the operation (see screenshot), but then there is a different endpoint that checks the actual request status.

Can this be implemented as one module in Integromat? Or should there be a separate module for checking the status?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - you will need 2x HTTP (blue) circles for this.

In my example- I would authenticate first using some API and get authentication parameter from that first API call.. then I would pass it to the next HTTP Blue circle API call.

Although more information is needed in your question, I feel the answer would be 2 subsequent HTTP API calls within Integromat